# Hibernate: no persistent classes found for query class but mapping is correct

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, ejb-3.0

This question has been asked many times, but I have not encountered a solution for my problem as on first sight everything seems right. It is a configuration problem when using this Hibernate setup:

- hibernate-core: 5.2.11.Final
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api: 1.0.0.Final
- hibernate-commons-annotations: 5.0.1.Final

When I try to execute a query I get a warning in the console that says **no persistent classes found for query class** but no error is thrown, and no data is retrieved from database although it should return over 30 entries.

```
09:56:58,203 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (default task-46) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.11.Final}
09:56:58,206 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (default task-46) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
09:56:58,348 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (default task-46) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
09:56:58,397 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-46) HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
09:56:58,398 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-46) HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_motor?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true]
09:56:58,398 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-46) HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=admin, password=****}
09:56:58,398 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling] (default task-46) HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
09:56:58,400 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (default task-46) HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10 (min=1)
09:56:58,647 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (default task-46) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
09:56:58,958 WARN  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter] (default task-46) HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: SELECT respuestas FROM mr.hibernate.beans.MR_RespuestasHBean respuestas
09:56:58,959 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (default task-46) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

It seems the warning about **hibernate.properties not found** is not of any influence if I interpret information found on this website correctly.

The *hibernate.cfg.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="session_factory">
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.password">admin</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property> <!-- not for production -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_motor?useSSL=false&amp;autoReconnect=true</property>
        <property name="connection.username">admin</property>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
        <mapping class="mr.hibernate.beans.MR_RespuestasHBean"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The mapped class:

```
package mr.hibernate.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_respuestas")
public class MR_RespuestasHBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3892055031093758454L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COD_RESPUESTA", nullable = false, length = 11)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigoRespuesta;

    public Long getCodigoRespuesta() {
        return codigoRespuesta;
    }

    public void setCodigoRespuesta(Long codigoRespuesta) {
        this.codigoRespuesta = codigoRespuesta;
    }
}
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE t_respuestas
(
   COD_RESPUESTA int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX PRIMARY ON t_respuestas(COD_RESPUESTA)
;
```

The code used to get the query is this:

```
    session = getSession(HibernateUtil.configurationFileMySql);
    session.beginTransaction();

    StringBuffer hql = new StringBuffer();

    StringBuffer select = new StringBuffer();
    select.append("SELECT respuestas");

    StringBuffer from = new StringBuffer();
    from.append(" FROM "+ MR_RespuestasHBean.class.getName() +" respuestas");

    hql.append(select);
    hql.append(from);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Query<MR_RespuestasHBean> query = session.createQuery(hql.toString());

    listado = query.list();
```

If I change *MR_RespuestasHBean.class.getName()* by *MR_RespuestasHBean.class.getSimpleName()*, an error is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MR_RespuestasHBean is not mapped
```

Some information on the environment:

- JBoss EAP7
- JDK8
- MySql connector 6.0.6
- The Hibernate part is in an EJB3 project

However, when using this setup, everything works well (logically, session loading and query execution has to be different):

- hibernate-core: 4.2.0.Final
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api: 1.0.1.Final
- hibernate-commons-annotations: 4.0.1.Final

Any clues on what is causing the problem is very much appreciated.

Comment: The query goes like : "SELECT respuestas FROM mr.hibernate.beans.MR_RespuestasHBean respuestas" and the table is named "T_RESPUESTAS". Is the "t" missing?

Comment: You should select FROM "T_RESPUESTAS" not "class name" ...

Comment: it is look like hibernate fail in parsing that entity of yours, can you post the full MR_RespuestasHBean class?

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. I changed the query to T_RESPUESTAS but it throws a not mapped class error. In my local development I have changed the database table to one with just one field and have left the Hibernate bean to one field as well so to be able to debug the problem better, I have adapted the problem explanation to that scenario. Instead of T_RESPUESTAS I changed the entity mapping to t_respuestas since when I do a create script from MySql it is that table name that appears. Still the same error though.

Comment: Okay, so I have returned to some older Hibernate configuration setup that worked for me and now I got everything working so it probably has to do with a wrong setup of Hibernate libraries. I have edited the information listed above, if someone is able to point out what the incorrect configuration is, please let me know. Many thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, my setup was working on hibernate 4.3.1 updating to 5.2.13 resulted in Mapping not found, I also noticed the absence of Loading "pkg/mapping.hbm.xml" entries from the server log.